# Why I get no response from using curl?

Tags: php, curl, google-places-api, php-curl

I am trying to send GET request to Google places API but I get nothing ! here is my code:

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=restaurants+in+Sydney&key='.API_KEY);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

echo $query;
```

Update:

I found that testing this on localhost return blank page but if I uploaded to live domain it work !! any one know why it does not work on localhost ?

Comment: Are there any errors/warnings within the script file itself? Add "error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", true);" (without surrounding quotes) to the top of the file and check. Also are you using an AJAX call to access this script? Check in the Developer Console for any HTTP errors, or console.log() the result before trying to process it.

Comment: @GaryThomas I did all that but I only get 200 status in the network tab. I dont use ajax I just put the link in the browser like this: http://localhost/myapp/index.php

Comment: Seems dollar sign is missing in front of `API_KEY`, it should be `$API_KEY`

Comment: @LuisMuñoz No I use it with define('API_KEY', 'xxxxxx');

Comment: ok, what do you get with that URL on a browser?

Comment: blank page but network tab display 200 GET status

Comment: If you are getting a blank page in a browser then the problem is with your URL and/or API key. The issue is not with cURL if you get the same results in a browser.